# Proof method for non-equivalence of norms?

Tags: normed-spaces

Suppose I have 3 norms. I need to prove that any two of them are *not* equivalent. In my situation, proving that (1 and 3) and (2 and 3) are not equivalent is easy, but proving at (1 and 2) are not equivalent is very hard.

Is it sufficient to prove that norms (1 and 3) are not equivalent and norms (2 and 3) are not equivalent, and then just say that this means that (1 and 2) are also not equivalent? If so, why is this the case? What proof strategy does this relate to?

Comment: This is clearly not enough. What if (1) and (2) are the same norm?

Comment: But they aren't?

Comment: I'm simply giving a counterexample to your suggested line of reasoning, showing that it isn't valid.